# Accessing "Shadow Samples" on Photometric Lights via maxscript?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to find a way to access "shadow samples" property of "Photometric Area Lights" in 3ds max via maxscript, but for some reasons I can't find anything mentioned through documents!

[3Ds Max Area Light Shadow Samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsFen.jpg)

I even tried to guess what it would be called with no luck so far. "shadow_samples" would do for any mental ray portal lights for example, but nothing seems to work with area lights. So anyone with some experience or info on this who's willing to share would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out by getting a hand from Maxscript Macro Recorder! Will drop the answer here for others.

The actual path to access is something crazy:

```
<light>.baseObject.Area_Light_Sampling_Custom_Attribute.mr_NumAreaSamples
```